# PHP Mail: Cannot redirect user to the required page

Tags: php, laravel, email, ssl

I am sending an email for password reset form from my Laravel Project. I have included a link to the form page in the email and when user clicks on it, I want him to see the password reset page. But instead of the password reset page, the user is redirected to the home page.

This is email.blade.php file or the email which the user will receive:

```
<html>
<head><title>Reset Password</title></head>
<body>
<p>Please Click on the link below to change your password, </p>
<p>
<a href='http://findajob.af/change_password/<?php echo $username; ?>' target='_blank'>RESET PASSSWORD</a>
</p>
</body>
<html>
```

Now the problem here is, when the user clicks on the link, he is redirected to the home page which is `http://findajob.af/`. I want the user to be redirected to this page `http://findajob.af/change_password/<?php echo $username; ?>`.

This is the route to change password page:

```
Route::get('change_password/{username}',['uses' =>'General_controller@change_password']);
```

Please note that this code works fine on my localhost where I am using mailtrap.io

Comment: probably an issue with your route definition. Hard to help with so few information.

Comment: this is the route : Route::get('change_password/{username}',['uses' =>'General_controller@change_password']);

Comment: And are you sure that you can access this page without being logged in ?

Comment: Yes I am sure. User can access this page without logged in

Comment: I got the problem. The link in the email looks like 'findajob.af/change_password/username', instead of 'http://findajob.af/change_password/username'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your **RESET PASSWORD** link like:

```
<a href='http://findajob.af/change_password/'.$username' target='_blank'>RESET PASSSWORD</a>
```

Hope this work for you !!!